# Word Press Permalink Change

Tags: seo, permalinks

I had the following permalink structure in my WordPress blog:

```
/%category%/%post-name%/
```

I changed it to:

```
/%post-name%/
```

Everything is fine as I am using the permalink finder plugin, which redirects the posts to new address. But, the issue is that Google Webmaster Tools shows too many duplicate meta descriptions as follows:

- /category1/postid/
- /postid/

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

this is corrent; WordPress generated always an permalink for each post with category and tag; you must dofollow this for the bots on your robots.txt, like `Disallow: */?tag=*` or `Disallow: /category/*/*`

See also [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Search_Engine_Optimization_for_WordPress) for this topic.